# Custom authentication in Java REST API

Tags: java, facebook, rest, authentication, jersey

I'm trying to come up with the best way to do my own authentication in our Java REST API using the Jersey framework (v2.5.1) running on Tomcat 7.

The API will be accessed through our iOS application. In the iOS application we use Facebook authentication (using the Facebook SDK), and then we use the access token in every call to the REST API.

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException
    {
        // Extract the access token from the HTTP header
        // Look up in the database to see if we have a user with that token
        // If there is a user found, proceed
        // If we can't find a user, we are going to send the token to Facebook to get the user details. If the token is invalid, we throw an exception. If it is valid, we look up if we can match the Facebook details with an existing user. When we can't match, we create a new user.
    }
}
```

*This filter will be executed in every API request.*

My questions:

- Is this a correct workflow?
- Should we contact Facebook every time to validate the token? This will cause a lot of overhead.
- This filter is executed for every request. How can we exclude certain urls (some resources won't require authentication)? I was thinking of holding a set of urls in the filter class and see if the requested url matches one of the defined public urls (if so, don't do the authentication).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be better if you can provide this option to your user:
login / login using facebook account.
So you dont have to contact Facebook unless user choose to login using their FB account.
also, the authentication should be session based. session information can includes user, session key, valid time range, maybe source IP too. once the user has successfully logged in, a session is generated. then for every request you only have to check if the session key is still valid.